Webdriver RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
I'm starting a web scraping project and I need to setup a driver. I'm doing it like this:
import logging
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from RPA.FileSystem import FileSystem

class CustomSelenium:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.driver = None
        self.file = FileSystem()


    def set_chrome_options(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        return options

    def set_webdriver(self):
        # options = self.set_chrome_options()
        # service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        print("WebDriver initialized successfully.")

my_driver = CustomSelenium()
my_driver.set_webdriver()

It used to work fine, but now I'm getting the error:
[Previous line repeated 488 more times] RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
After some tries I noticed the error didn't occur when I removed the 'service' part:
    def set_webdriver(self):
        # options = self.set_chrome_options()
        # service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        print("WebDriver initialized successfully.")

However, I'm unsure if this changes something important, I would appreciate some help.
My versions:
dependencies:
  - python=3.10.12                    # https://pyreadiness.org/3.10
  - pip=23.2.1                        # https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news
  - robocorp-truststore=0.8.0         # https://pypi.org/project/robocorp-truststore/
  - nodejs=16.20.2                    # https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
  - pip:
    - robotframework-browser==17.5.2  # https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser/releases

edit:
I noticed the same error occurs when I do:
response = requests.get(url)


You don't need Service in modern selenium versions. webdriver.Chrome() will suffice (with options if required)

There are 2 reasons this happens, first the recursion happens in the
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

stage, but I'm not sure why. I think it's because the driver is already going to be installed anyway;
And the next reason is that requests.get() tries to contact the given url, but with no success. So you have to use .get(verify=False).

You don't need Service with latest selenium version(s). I suggest:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

class CustomSelenium:
    def __init__(self):
        self._driver = None
        self._options = None
    @property
    def driver(self):
        if self._driver is None:
            self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        return self._driver
    @property
    def options(self):
        if self._options is None:
            self._options = ChromeOptions()
            self._options.add_argument('--headless')
            self._options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            self._options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            self._options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            self._options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
            self._options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            self._options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
            self._options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        return self._options
    def close(self):
        if self._driver is not None:
            self._driver.close()
            self._driver = None

cs = CustomSelenium()

try:
    driver = cs.driver
    # use the driver in some way here
finally:
    # ensure that driver is properly closed
    cs.close()

Platform:
Python 3.12.5
selenium 4.23.1

Note:
Of course, it would be much better to modify your class so that it can be used as a context manager

Hi @SIGHUP, thanks for the answer, but what would be a context manager?

@fatbee7 You could either implement a decorated function as described here or implement the __enter__ and __exit__ dunder methods in your class
